# How to make the @RestController do not response data as restful?

Tags: redirect, spring-boot, controller, spring-restcontroller

I want to response a type of String as "redirect:http://www.stackoverflow.com" and expected that the browser would auto redirect to the address as what I want. But, it was failed when I use a "`@RestController`".(based on SpringBoot 1.3.5.RELEASE)

```
@RestController    
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestRestController {

    @RequestMapping("/rest_controller")
    public String testResponse() {
        return "redirect:http://stackoverflow.com/";
    }
}
```

but the following can make the redirect succeed when use "`@Controller`".

```
@Controller    
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {   
    @RequestMapping("/not_rest_controller")
    public String testResponse() {
        return "redirect:http://stackoverflow.com/";
    }
}
```

and I want to know how to make the `@RestController` also succeed as the `@Controller`.

Comment: Why do you want to force `@RestController`instead of `@Controller` ?

Comment: A RestController is a specialized Controller which is intended to return the return value as response body. So if you don't want that, don't use it. Controller is for what you want to do.

Comment: @MickaëlB  sometimes, I make a class as `@RestController`, and I want to response a `String` to tell the browser to redirect as what I want at a mapping `@RequestMapping`. But now I have to make a new class and have to annotate it with `@Controller`. so I want to know if there have sth special way that I don't have to make a new class and make it possible by `@RestController` .